# How I can not filter Websocket with Shiro

Tags: java, websocket, shiro

I have a web application I implemented **Shiro Security** the problem now is the WebSocket is not working.

I try telling Shiro allow anonymous to **/device where the WebSocket is running.**

Shiro urls part (shiro.ini file):

```
[urls]
/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/public/**  = anon
/device/* = anon
/* = authc
```

Comment: Is ' /device/** =anon ' not working? Yoy can also try with this pattern in the top of the list since shiro ends verifying patterns when one fits.

Comment: Thanks @GarciGarcía, that works for me.